# SKShapeNode not filling on first time

Tags: macos, swift, sprite-kit

When I add the follow code , the first sprite is not fill , but the others  is normals ( filled red rects )
Anyone know if its is an Bug of Swift in Xcode 7.0 or something thats is missing in GCPath or SKShapeNode configuration

The code is the same of Game Template for OS X with some changes

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

}


func getSprite() -> SKShapeNode
{
    let aPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddRect(aPath,nil,   CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    let shapeNode = SKShapeNode()
    shapeNode.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
    shapeNode.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()

    shapeNode.lineWidth = 1
    shapeNode.path =  aPath
    shapeNode.zPosition = 2
    return shapeNode
}


override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    /* Called when a mouse click occurs */

    let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)

    let sprite = getSprite() //SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
    sprite.position = location;
    sprite.setScale(0.5)

    let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)
    sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

    self.addChild(sprite)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

Comment: I really have no idea what caused the issue. But I have two points to share: 1. Draw anything in `didMoveToView` will eliminate the issue. 2. The issue doesn't exist on iOS 8 & 9 using the same code.